How do I check the correct oil level in 2016 Equinox 3.6L V6?
I have synthetic Dexos1 and check every few months in the morning before I start the car for the first time but it is a struggle because I do not understand the manual's description. The manual says "If the oil is below the cross-hatched  area at the tip of the dipstick add 1 qt of recommended oil". When I pull the dipstick out it shows two different readings depending on which side I look. No matter how fast or how slow I remove the dipstick the oil always runs up one side and that oil drips over to the other side so I can not clearly see the line on either side definitively. The manual does not mention this feature.
For sure it is not below the lowest cross-hatched area. I would guess it is the middle of the cross-hatched area.
If anyone has any ideas how I can get a cleaner reading please let me know.

A couple of photos may help others to understand what you're seeing.

That's a good idea. ...I will research and see if I can learn to send a picture from iPhone to Stackexchange.

The typical practice for checking oil level is to remove the dipstick, wipe it clear of oil, then fully replace it. Removing it a second time will provide a clearer indication. Obviously, you won't want to turn the stick around, but if the mechanicals require rotation of the dipstick for insertion and removal, note the oil level on the second removal and use it as a reference for the cross-hatching.

Thank you for the advice, I am going to try what you suggest tomorrow morning. I like to wait until the engine is cold and the oil totally drained to the bottom. If it still doesn't seem to work then I will send a pic.

Even when the engine sits idle, you'll get capillary action of the oil on the stick, especially over an extended period of time. Letting the engine sit is a good idea for accuracy, but the double dip with a wipe in the middle removes the capillary complication.

I do not know what the "double dip with a wipe in the middle" is. I wipe the stick clean. How do you do a double dip? By the way I did try it again but with the same results. One side of the stick is at the second notch. There are five in cross-hatch area. When I turn it over it is wet allmost to the top, although the oil is not as thick as the other side. I will demonstrate it to the auto repair service I use on Monday and see what he says. I can post a comment to let you know what he says in case someone might be interested.

The first "dip" is the stick in the oil. Removing it, wiping it and inserting/removing it is the second one, although I really should have said "double pull" or "double removal."

No worries, Today was Sunday and the dealer is closed but tomorrow I will ask. I will drive there and have him watch me as I check the oil. I am very curious to see what he says.
